# Efficiency problems when combining CONTAINS with conditional logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just made a modification to the `WHERE` clause of a query I was using to return some search results.

I started with:

```
WHERE 
(
    CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Forename, @Forename) 
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @FamilyName)
) 
AND 
(
    MD_Entity_Role.Role_Type = 2
    OR MD_Entity.Do_Not_Transact = 1
)
```

and changed it to:

```
WHERE 
(
    CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Forename, @Forename) 
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @FamilyName) 
    AND MD_Entity_Role.Role_Type = 2
)
OR 
(
    CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @Forename) 
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @FamilyName) 
    AND MD_Entity.Do_Not_Transact = 1
)
```

The query went from returning results instantly, to taking north of a minute.

I'm no `SQL` expert so I've evidently made some kind of efficiency faux pas here. First of all, can someone explain why the efficiency dropped so dramatically, and secondly, is there a quicker approach to what I've done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder the conditions, the faster the first

```
WHERE 
(   1 = 1
    AND MD_Entity_Role.Role_Type = 2
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Forename, @Forename) 
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @FamilyName) 

)
OR 
(   1 = 1
    AND MD_Entity.Do_Not_Transact = 1
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @Forename) 
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @FamilyName) 
)
```

Using `UNION` to avoid slow `OR` condition

```
WHERE 
    1 = 1
    AND MD_Entity_Role.Role_Type = 2
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Forename, @Forename) 
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @FamilyName) 

UNION

WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND MD_Entity.Do_Not_Transact = 1
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @Forename) 
    AND CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @FamilyName)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The UNION made all the difference. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
It might allow query optimizer to filter sooner

```
WHERE 
CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @FamilyName)
AND 
(
  (
    CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Forename, @Forename) 
    AND MD_Entity_Role.Role_Type = 2
  )
  OR 
  (
    CONTAINS(MD_Entity.Family_Name, @Forename)          
    AND MD_Entity.Do_Not_Transact = 1
  )
)
```